# RTOS supported by STM32 L1 series

Tags: stm32, rtos

Which all are the RTOS supported by STM32L151 micro controller. From the Web sites I can understand that it support FreeRTOS but is there any other RTOS which can be used with this series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bearing in mind the the restricted memory resources of some STM32L151 series parts, any RTOS that targets ARM Cortex-M3 and has sufficiently small footprint can be supported.

Unlike earlier ARM microcontroller architectures Cortex-M defines a system clock and interrupt controller within the core making an RTOS largely independent of the manufacturer specific part.  Moreover ARM's CMSIS specification promotes far greater portability between parts in any case.

So essentially you should be looking for Cortex-M support from an RTOS rather than STM32L151 specific support.  Part specific support is likely to relate only to middleware and driver support where provided.  Since most mainstream portable RTOS products in current production can target Cortex-M there is no point in providing a list here.  A list is maintained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_real-time_operating_systems).  Products specifically listed on [ST's website](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/tools/FM147/CL1794/SC961/SS1743/LN1900) include CMX, ThreadX, FreeRTOS and SafeRTOS.  I am currently using Segger embOS on STM32, but have also used Keil's RTX library included with thier ARM-MDK tools.

Answer (score 1):

STM32 series supports Netx/ThreadX RTOS also,actually they provides the compiled binary files so that we could only access them using some API's , but its easy and good to use.

Broadcom is providing WICED IDE/SDK where generally STM32 controllers are interfaced with Broadcom BCM43362 WI-FI chipset , you could download and use it from Broadcom's website.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the RTOS support STM32 series chipsets, such as FreeRTOS, ucOS, Keil's RTX and the new embedOS developed by ARM. But for STM32L151, only the FreeRTOS is supported officially, because the STM32CubeMX will generate the project including the FreeRTOS source code which has been adopted to this IC. For other RTOS, you should port them by yourslef if you want running them on STM32L151, and of course they support STM32L151.